# How to use Katex css in React Native html content rendering from react native render html

Tags: javascript, react-native

well am using katex in react web application rendering with `katex.min.css` `https://katex.org/docs/browser.html` when coming to react native only html data getting rendering, here how can achieve this render katex class while importing `katex css`

for html using this npm

```
npm i react-native-render-html
```

my example code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

solved with WebView by react native WebView package